# Questions about how to choose proper hardware

Tags: discussion

I asked this [question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96006/processors-e5-4620-v2-vs-e5-2620-v3).  Which is put on hold for asking for a product.  But really (as seen in the last line), I'm asking how to choose.  How can I edit this question to make it acceptable?

Comment: How do you choose is probably considered too broad or opinionated. So, it'd still be closed, just not as a shopping list.

Comment: You can look at things like Glen Berry's blog and try to divine what factors he finds important but the optimal hardware for an OLTP would be different for a DW. And then you have to consider: do I have an SLA? What volume of data will I have? What constraints do I have, etc, etc etc

Comment: I do not disagree and not knowing about Glen's blog before, I'm glad that this question brought it to me.  The meta question is just an attempt to not have a lot of discussion in comments.